# Is it possible to trace browser history in a PHP code?

Tags: php, browser-history

I want to know that whether on a php page we can get browser history?
Suppose I want to display a php page if a specific link on that browser has been visited earlier otherwise a blank page is to be displayed.
Is it possible to do so??

Comment: Is it a page from your own site, or someone elses?

Comment: No it is not possible unless its your own domain... Think of the insecurity's if it was

Comment: If you can keep track of that person having been on the page, if it is calling your php program, then you can, otherwise php only gets what was in the http request, and knows nothing about what is on the browser.

Comment: There's certain hacks with CSS that can 'leak' history data, but browsers are starting to close that kind of hole. In general, you can NOT spy on a user's history, nor should you even try. It's a hideous breach of privacy to do so.

Comment: @BugFinder if it is from my own site than some manipulation can solve I hope.I want to know for someone else's page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it is your own site, you can store a session variable to confirm they went there, do something like

```
session_start();
$SESSION["VisitedMySpecialPage"]=time();
```

and then in the checker page

```
session_start();
if (isset($SESSION["VisitedMySpecialPage"]))
{
 // check here it was within say the last hour..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can track what pages where visited on your own domain, but you can't check what other domains he visited. You can check the referer header to see what site he came from , but that's only 1 site and isn't very reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there was workaround to this problem some time ago, I don't know which browser still can do it:

- place `<a>` tag with href attr to link what you are interested on your
- inspect `<a>` node (via `JS`), if that link got `:visited` pseudo class send
- send result via ajax to server